# This code is giving me error I do not know where I am going wrong?

Tags: python

```
class Book():
    def __init__(self, listOfBooks):
        self.availableBooks = listOfBooks       

    def displayAvailableBook(self):
        print()
        self.displayAvailableBook()


class TextBooks(Book):

    def __init__(self,listOfBooks):
        super().__init__(listOfBooks)

    def displayAvailableBook(self):
        print()
        print("Available Text Books: ")
        print("--------------------")
        for book in self.availableBooks:
            print(book)
        print()


class ReferenceBooks(Book):

    def __init__(self,listOfBooks):
        super().__init__(listOfBooks)

    def displayAvailableBook(self):
        print()
        print("Available Reference Books: ")
        print("-------------------------")
        for book in self.availableBooks:
            print(book)
        print()

def main():
    book = Book()
    t_books = TextBooks(['Rescued by Python','Introduction to AI', 'Machine Learning using Python'])
    r_books = ReferenceBooks(['Dictionary','Bible','Encyclopidia'])

    while True:
        print("Enter 1 to display the available text books")
        print("Enter 2 to display the available reference books")
        print("Enter 3 to request for a book")
        print("Enter 4 to return a book")
        print("Enter 5 to exit")
        userChoice = int(input())

        if userChoice is 1:
            book.displayAvailableBook()
        elif userChoice is 2:
            r_books.displayAvailableBook()
        elif userChoice is 3:
            requestedBook = customer.requestBook()
            t_books.lendBook(requestedBook)
        elif userChoice is 4:
            returnedBook = customer.returnBook()
            t_books.addBook(returnedBook)
        elif userChoice is 5:
            quit()

main()
```

Comment: Whar error are you getting?

Comment: This program giving me error , I do not know where I am going wrong? Please help me

Comment: You said that already. Please post the complete error message including traceback.

Comment: It looks like you aren't passing a `listOfBooks` when you create a `book` object, although it is required

Comment: `customer` is not defined in the `main` function.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Since you didn't provide the requested error message, it's hard for us to help you.

Comment: BTW, your function `displayAvailableBook` is infinitely recursive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not pass an argument to your class Book():

```
def main():
   book = Book()
```

This is an issue since the **init** must be supplied by one parameter called listOfBooks in your code. Therefore, to solve your issue, supply a name to the Book constructor:

```
def main():
    bookList = ['a','b','c']
    book = Book(bookList)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going wrong in that code:
1.) You cannot initialize the class object Book without providing a list of books.
2.) You never initialize the object customer
3.) The class functions requestBook(), lendBook() and addBook() are not defined.

Here is a modified version that I think does what you want but I cannot solve the issues 2.) and 3.) since I do not know what you intend to do there

```
class Book():
    def __init__(self, listOfBooks):
        self.availableBooks = listOfBooks

    def displayAvailableBook(self):
        print()
        self.displayAvailableBook()


class TextBooks(Book):

    def __init__(self,listOfBooks):
        super().__init__(listOfBooks)

    def displayAvailableBook(self):
        print()
        print("Available Text Books: ")
        print("--------------------")
        for book in self.availableBooks:
            print(book)
        print()


class ReferenceBooks(Book):
    def __init__(self,listOfBooks):
        super().__init__(listOfBooks)

    def displayAvailableBook(self):
        print()
        print("Available Reference Books: ")
        print("-------------------------")
        for book in self.availableBooks:
            print(book)
        print()

def main():
    #book = Book() This does not work since no list provided
    t_books = TextBooks(['Rescued by Python','Introduction to AI', 'Machine Learning using Python'])
    r_books = ReferenceBooks(['Dictionary','Bible','Encyclopidia'])

    while True:
        print("Enter 1 to display the available text books")
        print("Enter 2 to display the available reference books")
        print("Enter 3 to request for a book")
        print("Enter 4 to return a book")
        print("Enter 5 to exit")
        userChoice = int(input())

        if userChoice is 1:
            t_books.displayAvailableBook()
            r_books.displayAvailableBook()
        elif userChoice is 2:
            r_books.displayAvailableBook()
        elif userChoice is 3:
            requestedBook = customer.requestBook()
            t_books.lendBook(requestedBook)
        elif userChoice is 4:
            returnedBook = customer.returnBook()
            t_books.addBook(returnedBook)
        elif userChoice is 5:
            quit()

main()
```

Answer (score -1):

The error you are getting is most likely a `TypeError` coming from line 38. From what I can see, it is because you have left out the parameters on the creation of the book object (`book = Book()`).

In your class definition, you have made it so that you need to pass a list of books, which you haven't included in the creation of the object.